# Is there an extension-centric changelog for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The [official changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/) is quite verbose, and mentions a lot of things that aren't relevant to extension development. I'm developing an extension and I want to know how far backwards-compatible it is (to fill in the `engines.vscode` property in package.json). Short of reading the entire changelog or downloading several versions to bisect compatibility, is there any easy way to tell when the features I'm using were introduced?

Comment: read the release notes, they mention upcoming API additions and released API additions, or just use the latest vscode version, or the version of VSC you use

Comment: @rioV8 What release notes do you mean? If it's not the one I already linked, could you provide a link to it?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_62